# jQuery - draggable clone and start dragginge on mousedown

Tags: jquery, draggable, droppable

I have some html like so:

```
<div>
    <button>Clone the parent</button>
    <div>Drag the parent</div>
</div>
```

The parent is a jQuery draggable. When anything other than the button is clicked, I want to drag the entire parent to a new location.

However, if the button gets a mousedown, I want to clone the parent, and begin dragging the clone around.

I thought I could use the draggable("option", "helper", "clone|original") method inside the "start" method, but this does not seem to take affect until after the mouse goes down again.

So, instead, I was just manually, cloning the parent when the button is clicked, but I can't figure out how to make the cloned parent play nice with droppable and having a the clone move on mousemove, since I need all this take place when the mouse goes down.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Why couldn't you change the option on the `mousedown`? That would fire before the `dragstart`

Comment: @DaveStein, Well, I don't know. It just does not seem to work. I think I've figured something out. I'm just always using the helper as a clone, and then doing the test in the drop function, and returning false to send the original back. It's not my ideal situation, but it will work.

Comment: Changing things on start is pretty bug in current implementation of UI